# Three.js: unable to tween objects position var (getting null error), but object itself is actually available

Tags: javascript, inheritance, canvas, three.js, gsap

Trying to target my `pig` objects `position` var with the function `flyUp()`. But `pig.position` in the function `flyUp()` is getting a `null` error. However, the object `pig` is actually available in the `flyUp()` function. I'm also getting the error `THREE.Object3D.add: object not an instance of THREE.Object3D` on `Pig` and `createPig`. What am I doing wrong here?

[Here's a plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/rCsmTDf6tQ8ZcbkGjkqh?p=preview)

Here's the relevant js:

```
function createPig(){
  pig = new Pig();
 scene.add(pig.threegroup);
}

Pig.prototype.update = function() {
  this.wingAngle += this.wingSpeed/globalSpeedRate;
  this.wingL.rotation.z = -Math.PI / 4 + Math.cos(this.wingAngle) * this.wingAmplitude;
  this.wingR.rotation.z = Math.PI / 4 - Math.cos(this.wingAngle) * this.wingAmplitude;
}

function getFlyPosition(){
    scene.updateMatrixWorld(true);
    var position = new THREE.Vector3();
    position.setFromMatrixPosition(pig.matrixWorld );
    objectHeight = position.y;
    flyTime = Math.round(position.y/30);
    console.log('cube Y = ' + position.y + ', Flytime = ' + flyTime);
}


function flyUp(){
  console.log(this.pig);
    if (objectHeight < maxHeight) {
      TweenLite.to(pig.position, 2.0, {y: "+=45", ease:Expo.easeOut} );
      } else { 
        flyDown();
    }
}

function flyDown(){
    getFlyPosition();
    TweenLite.to(pig.position, flyTime, {y: 25, ease:Sine.easeInOut} );
}
```

Here's the errors in full:

```
**error 1**
THREE.Object3D.add: object not an instance of THREE.Object3D. undefinedT
HREE.error @ three.js:35
THREE.Object3D.add @ three.js:7770
Pig @ script.js:452
createPig @ script.js:160
(anonymous function) @ script.js:553

**error 2**
Uncaught Cannot tween a null target.(anonymous function) @        TweenMax.min.js:16
D.to @ TweenMax.min.js:17
flyUp @ script.js:515
handleMouseDown @ script.js:100

**error 3**
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'elements' of undefined
THREE.Vector3.setFromMatrixPosition @ three.js:2389
getFlyPosition @ script.js:505flyDown @ script.js:522
handleMouseUp @ script.js:104
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I have been able to debug:

- The first error is because you have not initialised `this.tailSpiral` object like the way you have initialised other objects such as `this.torso` or `this.wingL` etc. This error happens at line: **452** of your *plnkr's* `script.js` file. Commenting out this line temporarily, fixes the issue. So basically, you need to create a ThreeJS object for `tailSpiral` like what you are doing the rest of them.
- For second error, from what I can tell, `pig` object doesn't have a `position` property on itself. Rather, the `position` object is available within `body` object which is available within the `pig` object. This error happens at line: **514** and will also happen at: **522**. So, these lines need to look something like: `TweenLite.to(pig.body.position, 2.0, { y: ... });`.
- And finally, same thing for the error at line: **505**. The property `matrixWorld` is not directly available to the `position` object. Rather, a `body` object sits between them. So this line needs to look like: `position.setFromMatrixPosition(pig.body.matrixWorld);`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Tahir you rock, thank you so much, my pig can now fly.   Good catch on `tailSpiral`, it should have said `tail`. And the position object was on `threegroup`. Thanks you helped point me in the right direction!!